# How can i only get the values from a array ([type: string]: string)

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an array typed like this :

```
array: {
    [type: string]: string;
}
```

and i want to get all values from it without any keys.

I tried to get it in several ways but nothing..

Here is an example of code :

```
const array: {
    [field: string]: string
} = {};

array['someProperty1'] = 'value1'
array['somePropert2'] = 'value2'
```

Here if i console log `array` i get

```
{
    array: {
        someProperty1: 'value1',
        someProperty2: 'value2'
}
}
```

And i just want to get an array with ['value1', 'value2']

Comment: pls share reproducable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call 'array' is not technically an array, but rather a dictionary, but you can easily get the values using `Object.values`:

```
const realArray = Object.values(array);
```